# Limit groupings to the first x rows for each result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a time-series table like this:

```
Key | Value | Epoch
```

It could store many values for each Key, all marked with when then item was generated (epoch time).  Let's say I have 100 values per key, I want to average the value of the last 50, but only if has a statistically significant amount of data, let's say 20.  Currently, I have:

```
select key, avg(value)
from t
where
epoch > (select epoch from t order by epoch desc limit 50, 1)
group by key
having count(*) > 20
```

This performs pretty slowly and it uses a MySQL extension on the limit keyword.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.key, avg(t.value)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by key order by epoch desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by key) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 50 and cnt >= 20
group by t.key;
```

Both this and your version should be able to take advantage of an index on `(key, epoch desc)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` window functions:

```
select t.key, avg(t.value) avg_value
from (
 select *,
    count(*) over (partition by key) counter,
    row_number() over (partition by key order by epoch desc) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.counter > 20 and t.rn <= 50
group by t.key
```